# PDI Kettle Change Ojdbc file

Tags: oracle, pentaho, kettle, ojdbc, pdi

Im working at a new development plattform with PDI installed on it.

The plattform remains stable, but Im struggling with a problem since the moment we started to work on it and is related with the PDI behavour on some Oracle SQL queries. The problem is documented here: https://forums.pentaho.com/threads/53201-KETTLE-and-Oracle-s-NLS_DATE_FORMAT/

The subject of my question is:

I need to change the odbc jar file on /lib folder of PDI folders (change odbc10.jar to odbc6.jar) and I dont know how to do it. It can't be as simple as delete the wrong file and put the new one. I suppose that somewhere on PDI configuration there must be a setting pointing to the wrong odbc10.jar and I must set it with the name of the new driver that PDI must use (odbc6.jar). I'm not sure if this setting is neccesary or not. As I'm not admin on this server, I can´t on my own, change the file and test it, I need to open a IT Ticket and ask for the right department to do it and I dont wan't anyone loose their time with wrong instructions.

I hope you could explain me how to change this driver please.

Please..could any of you guys explain how to do it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's as simple as that. If you don't feel confident, instead of deleting the odbc10.jar change the name to odbc10.jar_old or something like that, so PDI doesn't pick this other version of the odbc jar file, so you have a backup of the file quickly available.